# Determine return type of Java method during method runtime

Tags: java

I have the below method in Java:

```
public <T> T get(int i, Class<T> type) {
    return (T) this.arr.get(i); //arr is just an ArrayList
}
```

This method works, but it has to be called as such:

```
int a = classObj.get(3, Integer.class);
```

As a second argument, I always have to pass the class of the object that I need returned. I'm looking for a way to not have to pass that second argument; I want to be able to call the method like this:

```
int a = classObj.get(3);
```

In other words, I want the return type to be whatever `this.arr.get(i).getClass()` returns. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: "*In other words, I want the return type to be whatever `this.arr.get(i).getClass()` returns. Is there any way I can achieve this?*" - No. The type must be known at compile-time. --- Two remarks: - `arr` seems to be a `List`. I would suggest to name it accordingly. - Casting with generic parameters can be strange wrt. where `ClassCastException`s occur. I would suggest to introduce an explicit check `type.isInstance(arr.get(i))`.

Comment: ```int a = classObj.get(3);``` If you try to achieve this, how would the compiler know what type of objects the ```ArrayList``` is holding. So the type must be known at compile-time by the compiler

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understood what you're trying to achieve, but I'm almost sure, that the design of your approach is not the cleanest and best. Besides, if you have at least some scope of the potentially returning type, you can declare your generic with some bounding wildcard.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri is right. This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you tell us about the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a python list in Java. My class saves data added to the list in an ArrayList of Objects. Therefore, everything is saved as an Object. However, when the user wants to get the data, I want it to be returned as its actual type. For instance, if the list is `[1, 2, 3]`, I want calling `l.get(1)` to return an integer, 2, so it can be used in operations. Returning an Object doesn't allow this, but I don't want the class to have to be passed as a second argument. I realize this might not be possible, though.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, while Java is statically typed. In statically typed languages, all types must be known at compile-time for type-checking.

Comment: @ZeroFunter please don't just try to copy the logic from completely different language. Its semantics, behaviour, the way it implements Lists (and Java does in case of `ArrayList` or other `List`s), and etc. are very different. In your case, I guess you either need to bound your generic type parameter, or case unsafely, which is very bad habit.